# Jquery UI dialog properties with dynamic dialog messages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a form with a handful of asp.net texboxes/dropdownlists/radiobuttonlists etc and when I click submit I have an onclientclick event that does a validation check of all the controls. I want to use the Jquery UI dialog for error popups but I need a different message for each form element validation. This is what I'm doing now, and it works, but the style valign isn't working and I'm not sure how else to manipulate the dialog's properties when I'm declaring it this way. I have a background in C++ so I'm still fairly new to client side scripting.

```
        if (Page_ClientValidate())
        {
            var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
            newDiv.attr("title", "Required Field");
            newDiv.attr("style", "vertical-align:top");

            if ($("#txtFirstName").val() == "") {
                $("#txtFirstName").focus();
                newDiv.html('Please enter your first name');
                newDiv.dialog();
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: your code is right. test for example 'newDiv.css("background", "red");'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing with your code seems to show a dialog that appears as expected - title in the title bar, message below that.  Did you include the relevant jquery UI css reference?

If you want to carry out more detailed styling, just include class tags in your html (ie 'Please enter your first name') and you can set styles for that class in your css as usual.

```js
function validate() {
  var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
  newDiv.attr("title", "Required Field");

  if ($("#txtFirstName").val() == "") {
    $("#txtFirstName").focus();
    newDiv.html('Please enter your first name');
    newDiv.dialog({
  position: { my: "center top", at: "center top", of: window }
});
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<input type="textbox" name="txtFirstName" id="txtFirstName" />
<button onclick="validate();return false;">Validate</button>
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the dialog box to pop up where the normal javascript alert box would so it's somewhat consistent to my users. But that style attribute change doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Updated the code snippet to show the use of position option in dialog()

Comment: I swear I tried that and it didn't work. I'm guessing I just didn't have the syntax just right, thank you for your help!